# Unique Join: 2 Primary Keys to one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, primary-key

The issue I am having is working with 3 tables Customer, Purchase and Workflow.

CustomerID is the Primary key for Customer Table and is a 3 digit INT
EG.. 123

PurchaseID is the primary key for the Purchase Table is a 8 digit INT
EG.. 12345678

Workflow holds the details of what workflow the user is running at the time. Depending on the task it can vary. It may look like this.

```
WFID    EntityID        Type        Ref

771     123             Customer    1
772     12345678        Purchase    2
773     124             Customer    1
774     125             Customer    1
775     12345679        Purchase    2
```

The primary key for these 2 tables is mixed into the single entityID column and this is causing me a lot of difficulty to join. I have managed to do this joining on a case statement after the (ON Workflow.EntityID =) which looks like this.

```
ON Workflow.EntityID =)
Case    when ref = 1 THEN customer.customerID
    When ref = 2 THEN purchase.purchaseID
END
```

But the query I am running then becomes so slow and unresponsive that it’s not really a solution.

Has anyone had any other experience with these type of joins, where a column combines a mixture of 2 primary keys from separate tables?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I suggest that change Workflow schema to WFID, CustomerID, PurchaseID, Type, Ref

Answer (score 3):

A condition like that in a `join` makes it really hard to optimize the query.  Try writing it as two separate joins:

```
from workflow wf left outer join
     customer c
     on c.customerID = wf.EntityID and wf.ref = 1 left outer join
     purchase p
     on p.purchaseID = wf.EntityID and wf.ref = 2
```

The engine can do a much better job of optimizing these.

Comment: Thanks. Looks alot more stable that what I had previously

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union that will do the same job. This will work, but the design of you tables is not that good. You should reconsider db design in this case.

```
--query--
where ref = 1 and Workflow.EntityID = customer.customerID
union all
--query--
where ref = 2 and Workflow.EntityID = purchase.purchaseID
```

Comment: The UNION is something I have attempted but because I have multiple instances in the Workflow table and by no way they are unique I was getting duplicates when reporting. Thanks

Comment: UNION will give you the same results as the 2 joins, but with a smaller memory footprint and usually faster speed. Also it will keep the same result set as the original query.